# App engine favicon

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

Not entirely sure what I'm missing here but my favicon will not load. I am able to visit localhost:8080/favicon.ico and see the image but its not in the tab.

#### app.yaml

```
  handlers:
  - url: /favicon\.ico
    static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
    upload: static/images/favicon\.ico
```

#### index.html

```
<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
</head>
```

#### dir structure

```
.
├── static
│   ├── images
│   │   └── favicon.ico
```

Comment: no need for `favicon\.ico`, `favicon.ico` is just fine.

Comment: still doesn't fix the issue but good to know

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Not really. `favicon.ico` will also match `faviconaico`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I have, which is working, so it might help...

**app.yaml**:

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico
- url: /favicon\.png
  static_files: favicon.png
  upload: favicon\.png
```

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...>
    <head>
        ...
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.my_domain.com/favicon.png"></meta>
        ...
    </head>
</html>
```

The **favicon.ico** and **favicon.png** files are located alongside the **app.yaml** file.

Answer (score 4):

This will work:

```
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico
```

and a more complete:

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

If you can get to it directly, your app.yaml is working fine.  If the browser is not seeing it, it is most likely a cache issue.  Clear the cache, restart the browser.